# Invalid namespace prefix

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to create an element with *json:Array* as namespace that should look like this:

```xml
<foo json:Array="true"/>
```

But the following code throws *Invalid namespace prefix 'json:Array'* error.

```py
from lxml.etree import Element, tostring
tostring(Element("foo", nsmap={"json:Array": "true"}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the namespace prefix can't have a `:` in it and you're trying to set the entire prefix to `json:Array`. In that name, only `json` is the prefix.

One option is to use QName()...

```py
from lxml import etree

elem = etree.Element("foo", attrib={etree.QName("idk", "Array"): "true"}, nsmap={"json": "idk"})

print(etree.tostring(elem).decode())
```

This prints:

```xml
<foo xmlns:json="idk" json:Array="true"/>
```

Notice this is namespace well-formed because the `json` prefix is bound to the uri `idk` (replace with what you actually need).